# ¿cómo agregar a un input valor aleatorio?

Tags: php, html

tengo este PHP que imprime valores aleatorio

```
    <script>
     <?php
    $caracteres = "AB1234567890";
    $desordenada = str_shuffle($caracteres);
    $CH = substr($desordenada, 1, 4); }
    echo $CH;
    ?>  
 </script>
```

ahora mi duda es cómo hago para que ese valor se imprima en una caja del formulario, no tiene porque tener un botón para que genere el numero aleatorio sino que se genere al cargar la pagina. de antemano agradezco toda la orientación que me puedan dar. Gracias

```html
<form action="#">
<label>Codigo ID</label>
<input type="text" placeholder="Codigo aleatorio" >
</form>
```

Comment: No edites la pregunta con tu respuesta. Publícala como respuesta, y la marcas como correcta.

Answer (score 1):

Tu codigo esta mal planteado, no debes mezclar javascript con PHP y viceversa, son dos lenguajes que trabajan en lados distintos.

imprime con PHP directamente el valor, no hace falta pasarlo por javascript

```
<?php
$caracteres = "AB1234567890";
    $desordenada = str_shuffle($caracteres);
    $CH = substr($desordenada, 1, 4);
?>
<input value="<?php echo $CH ?>" />
```

En todo caso, si es necesario pasar por javascript por X motivo que tengas, debes hacerlo asi

```
<input type="text" id="idDemo">

<?php
$caracteres = "AB1234567890";
$desordenada = str_shuffle($caracteres);
$CH = substr($desordenada, 1, 4);
?>
<script>
    let idDemo = "<?php echo $CH ?>";
    window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    document.getElementById('idDemo').value = idDemo;
  });
</script>
```

Comment: muchas gracias por el consejo ,  y puse lo del javascript porque pensé que seria mas fácil pasarlo asi . gracias por tu respuesta. en cuanto el código lo intente pero no me funciono

Comment: el de javascript no te funciono?  si es así prueba utilizarlo en ES5  así como te lo puse esta en ES6....  para es5  en lugar de let  usa var  en lugar de () => {}  usa function(){}

Comment: sigue sin funcionar

Comment: ya solucione el problema , lo que hice fue agregar todo el PHP en value  lo voy a poner  por Si alguien tiene el mismo problema que yo y lo vea.

Answer (score 0):

Tan solo debes poner el valor obtenido en el `value` del `input`, puedes hacerlo así:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Codigo aleatorio" value="<?php echo $CH;?>">
```

Un ejemplo completo:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Online PHP Script Execution</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
        <?php
            $caracteres = "AB1234567890";
            $desordenada = str_shuffle($caracteres);
            $CH = substr($desordenada, 1, 4);   
        ?>  
        </script>   
        <form action="#">
            <label>Codigo ID</label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Codigo aleatorio" value="<?php echo $CH;?>">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**PROBLEMA SOLUCIONADO**

```
<div class="AL-M">
<label class="LB" for="random">N°Pedido:</label>
<input type="text" id="random" readonly  value="<?php
$caracteres = '123456789ABC';
    $aleatoria = substr(str_shuffle($caracteres), 0, 4);
    echo $aleatoria . "\n"; ?>">

</div>
```

para que esto te funcione tiene que estar en una plantilla PHP

Answer (score 0):

Se puede dar un value aleatorio sin php
Necesitas crear una plantilla JavaScript con .js , es importante que le pongas de nombre : script.js
Dentro de la plantilla importa exactamente lo que esta encerrado en corchetes con todo y espacios

---

```js
function pickRandom(argument) {
  if (typeof argument === 'number') {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(argument)) + 1;
  }
  if (Array.isArray(argument)) {
    return argument[Math.floor(Math.random() * argument.length)];
  }
}
```

ahora copia y pega esto

```js
function elNombreDeLaFuncion() { 
    
    document.getElementById("Remplazable").value = names;
    //primero copia la primera funcion y pegalo en la plantilla Javascript para que esto funcione :p , en el arreglo alli pones lo que quieras o lo remplazaz
}
function theSelector() {
  var names = pickRandom(['Mister Turtle','Ultra NPC','Generic    |      unicorn','Auto egg','MiniBoby','Ultra nova','Moon travel'])
   window.addEventListener('load',elNombreDeLaFuncion)
}
```

ahora crea un input en tu html y ponle un id='Remplazable' , luego copia esto    y ponlo en el  para que funcione el codigo y dale el value ,  se pueden hacer muchas cosas